# Having issues learning C++

Tags: c++

Okay so i am in the middle of learning C++ and i have come across an error i don't understand. My code is as follows...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    if (x == 1) {
        cout << "Red" << endl;
    }
    else if (x == 2) {
        cout << "blue" << endl;
    }
    else if (x == 3) {
        cout << "green" << endl;
    }
    else if (x == 4) {
        cout << "orange" << endl;
    }
    else if (x == 5) { 
        cout << "pink" << endl; 
    }

    string y;
    getline(cin, y);

    return 0;
}
```

So my issue is that the it seems to skip past the getline(cin, y) at the end.
My guess is that it is just something really obvious but i cant see anything. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: again the linefeed char from previous `cin >>` statement got in the way. Don't mix `getline` with `>>` input.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: Look at http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/111268/